# Visual Studio Code setup for Java WebApp Project without main method

Tags: java, maven, jsp, visual-studio-code

I am looking to setup this project ( https://github.com/afawcett/githubsfdeploy) on my local machine.  I'm not too familiar with Java but I feel I've been able to do enough (MAVEN, JAVA environment downloads and system variable settings) to get my windows machine up and running along with Visual Studio Code.  I was able to get the spring boot project up and running in visual studio code without any issues so I want to believe I have all the required pieces (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot).

The spring-boot project has a main method and the one I'm trying to recreate doesn't.  I am receiving the error when debugging the githubsfdeploy project that a "main" method could not be found.  I've been researching other ways to run a java project without using the main method but haven't recognized the missing piece yet.  Would love some direction on what I may not be taking into account. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Maven project which based on the concept of a project object model (POM). So first, you should download [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/) locally.

My machine: win10, vscode1.49.0, JDK11

VS Code Extension installed: **Java Extension Pack**, **Tomcat for java**

and i download: [apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip](https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip) and [Tomcat9.0.38](https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.38/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.38-windows-x64.zip) and extract them

1. Add maven to Environment Variables:

   **---\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin**
2. Open the project in VS Code, add the following code in User settings.json:

   **"maven.executable.path": "---\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn",**
3. Follow the picture steps:

[image]

4. Add the tomcat server and run the .war on tomcat, here is a gif tutorial: [work with tomcat](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tomcat-jetty#_tomcat)

Finally, you will observe this result:
[image]

When you can run it successfully, debugging is achievable: right click the tomcat server and choose **debug war packages**:

[image]

Comment: absolutely fantastic!! thank you! i was missing the tomcat download and extension!!