# Not able to run jsp file in spring boot using embedded tomcat server

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I have created a simple SpringBoot project to view jsp file.

Here is my Project tree - [image]

This is **MyappApplication.java**

```java
package com.simplespringboot.myapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyappApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Let's get started");
    }

}
```

This is TestController.java

```java
package com.simplespringboot.myapp;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String handler() {
        System.out.println("I am handler method");
        return "HI there ";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("I am home method");
        return "home";
    }

}
```

Application.properties

```java
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

This is my home.jsp file -

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <head>
            <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Insert title here</title>
            


        </head>

        <body>
            This is home view

        </body>

        </html>
```

This is my POM.xml file -

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.simplespringboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myapp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.37</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Whenever I am trying to my application this error is coming in the terminal -

```java
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.4)

2021-03-31 12:18:25.236  INFO 12940 --- [           main] c.s.myapp.MyappApplication               : Starting MyappApplication using Java 15.0.1 on LAPTOP-RP0N4VRN with PID 12940 (F:\Project2020\SPRINGBOOT\LastTry\myapp\target\classes started by hp in F:\Project2020\SPRINGBOOT\LastTry)
2021-03-31 12:18:25.242  INFO 12940 --- [           main] c.s.myapp.MyappApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-31 12:18:27.011  INFO 12940 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 
8080 (http)
2021-03-31 12:18:27.034  INFO 12940 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-03-31 12:18:27.035  INFO 12940 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache 
Tomcat/9.0.44]
2021-03-31 12:18:27.207 ERROR 12940 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]     
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]     
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]      
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]    
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]      
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]       
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at com.simplespringboot.myapp.MyappApplication.main(MyappApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]     
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]     
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/descriptor/tld/TldParser
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.<init>(TldScanner.java:84) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.newTldScanner(JasperInitializer.java:100) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]   
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
        ... 41 common frames omitted

2021-03-31 12:18:27.219 ERROR 12940 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]      
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]    
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]      
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]       
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at com.simplespringboot.myapp.MyappApplication.main(MyappApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]     
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]     
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]     
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]     
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/descriptor/tld/TldParser
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.<init>(TldScanner.java:84) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.newTldScanner(JasperInitializer.java:100) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]   
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
        ... 41 common frames omitted

2021-03-31 12:18:27.259  INFO 12940 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-03-31 12:18:27.270  WARN 12940 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; 
nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2021-03-31 12:18:27.294  INFO 12940 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-31 12:18:27.334 ERROR 12940 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]       
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at com.simplespringboot.myapp.MyappApplication.main(MyappApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]      
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]    
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]      
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start     
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]     
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]     
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]     
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]     
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/descriptor/tld/TldParser
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.<init>(TldScanner.java:84) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.newTldScanner(JasperInitializer.java:100) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]   
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
```

I have no idea what is the error. Somebody, please help me here. I am using VSCode.

Comment: The error means that VSCode didn't include `tomcat-embed-jasper.jar` in the classpath, when executing your project.

Comment: JSP only works with war files, not jar files. Second you reference JSTL in your JSP but haven't included the JSTL jars in your dependency list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open **Command Palette** and choose **Maven: Add a dependency**, type the missing jar name:

[image]

This is equals to add the following code in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then rebuild the project and see if the question goes away.

Comment: Hi @Molly Wang, Thanks a lot for the help. My Application (localhost:8080) is running, but it is not showing my home.jsp file (localhost:8080/home). The home() method in TestController.java is running as I can see output -[ I am home method ] in the terminal. Please help.

Comment: You may compile and deploy maven project to generate .war files. Then run the .war on Tomcat. Detailed steps please view my answer: [how to run a maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63910054/visual-studio-code-setup-for-java-webapp-project-without-main-method/63930087#63930087).